# How to use spring security to prevent xss and xframe attack

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I look [spring web site](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/headers.html)  and want to prevent my website form xss and xframe attack

But My english is not well enough to figure out what to set

Please guide me what else should I setting??

I just add a `WebSecurityConfig.java`  under `src/com/test/web/security`

Here is my code :

```
package com.test.web.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http
   // ...
   .headers();
}
}
```

Comment: Spring Security headers will prevent IFRAME hijacking and reflected XSS attacks but not normal XSS attacks. XSS relies on an application taking user's input and directly including it in a page's HTML. If the user supplied malicious JavaScript in the input, that JavaScript will execute, thereby hijacking the current user's privileges. XSS protection requires filtering malicious content and always escaping user-provided input. For the first, use a library such as HDIV. For the second, use the built-in features of whatever rendering mechanism you use - JSP, Facelets, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you just specify the same code that you have above, Spring Security should automatically add all of the relevant security headers. Per the docs:

> If you are using Spring Security’s Java configuration, all of the
>   default security headers are added by default.

Also:

> As soon as you specify any headers that should be included, then only
>   those headers will be include

See details and code samples in this section:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#default-security-headers

Comment: But I use owasp zap to attack,it stiil have those problem

Comment: Per the comment above, Spring Security won't defend against every attack. It will however add HTTP headers to defend against xframe, XSRF and a few other attack vectors. Check the docs for more details.

Comment: I have the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425632/spring-security-configuration-with-spring-boot) - using the Spring Boot defaults I still get the same OWASP ZAP warnings.  Were you able to get your security figured out?